# how do I execute javascript inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a big block of code that I cannot change and that is using document.write and overwrites the whole html document. I want to create an iframe inside that document and have that nasty code execute only inside that iframe which will be empty anyway so I wont mind. Is this possible?

Comment: Absolutely, use JS to create an iframe, a document, set the document's HTML (which includes your script or a reference to it) and assign the document to your iframe.

Comment: `var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;`
than access iframe's globals with `iframeDocument.myfunction()`